# What is the fastest way to combine two xml files into one

Tags: c#, xml

If I have  two string of xml1 and xml2 which both represent xml in the same format. What is the fastest way to combine  these together? The format is not important, but I just want to know how can I get rid off  or ?

xml1 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AllNodes>
   <NodeA>
      <NodeB>test1</NodeB>
      <NodeB>test2</NodeB>
   </NodeA>
</AllNodes>
```

xm2 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AllNodes>
   <NodeA>
      <NodeB>test6</NodeB>
      <NodeB>test7</NodeB>
   </NodeA>
   <NodeA>
      <NodeB>test99</NodeB>
      <NodeB>test23</NodeB>
   </NodeA>
</AllNodes>
```

and have something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AllNodes>
          <NodeA>
              <NodeB>test1</NodeB>
              <NodeB>test2</NodeB>
          </NodeA>
         <NodeA>
              <NodeB>test6</NodeB>
              <NodeB>test7</NodeB>
           </NodeA>
           <NodeA>
              <NodeB>test99</NodeB>
              <NodeB>test23</NodeB>
           </NodeA>
    </AllNodes>
```

Comment: For my own needs, [I've quickly written something to merge (web.config) XML files](http://pastebin.com/FzkRczZ6). There is also a [Configuration File Merger tool](https://configmerger.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using LINQ to XML. You can use either [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) or [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) depending on your needs.

```
var xml1 = XDocument.Load("file1.xml");
var xml2 = XDocument.Load("file2.xml");

//Combine and remove duplicates
var combinedUnique = xml1.Descendants("AllNodes")
                          .Union(xml2.Descendants("AllNodes"));

//Combine and keep duplicates
var combinedWithDups = xml1.Descendants("AllNodes")
                           .Concat(xml2.Descendants("AllNodes"));
```

Comment: well, the problem is I have two strings rather than two xml file. These two string represent xml elements which are sent from another station. Is there any way to cast my string to XElement or something like that?So I can walkthrough its elements?

Comment: To convert your string to XElement, you can use XElement.Parse(yourstring)

Comment: You can convert your string to a XDocument as well using XDocument.Parse(yourstring)

Comment: The answer from Jose Basilio is very good but incomplete, it will create a XElement IEnumerator with 2 "AllNodes" elements.
A more accurate answer would be (if duplicates are not an issue):

`xml1.Descendants("NodeA").LastOrDefault().AddAfterSelf(xml2.Descendants("NodeA"));
xml1.Save();`

Comment: @Vlax it was a wounderful completion, can you tell me how to save this file as a new file? like if xml2 is replaced with xml1 and I need to save as the result as xml3, is it possible?

Comment: How to get an XDocument back from combined?

Answer (score 9):

An XSLT transformation could do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="pXml1" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="pXml2" select="''" />
  <xsl:param name="pRoot" select="'root'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vXml1" select="document($pXml1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="vXml2" select="document($pXml2)" />

    <xsl:element name="{$pRoot}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="$vXml1/*/*" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="$vXml2/*/*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Pass in the names of the files as parameters, as well as the name of the new root element.

Apply to any XML document, e.g. an empty one.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution looks great, but do you know how I can apply that schema to an xml document?

Comment: For example, the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529374/whats-the-property-way-to-transform-with-xsl-without-html-encoding-my-final-outp shows how to do it in .NET

Comment: On the other hand - if you have no knowledge of XSLT whatsoever, it might not be the ideal solution for you. And I don't know how it will perform in comparison to the other ways suggested in this thread.

Answer (score 4):

This is the fastest and cleanest way to merge xml files.

```
XElement xFileRoot = XElement.Load(file1.xml);
XElement xFileChild = XElement.Load(file2.xml);
xFileRoot.Add(xFileChild);
xFileRoot.Save(file1.xml);
```

Comment: Will this keep or remove duplicates?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the XmlDocument, try this

```
 var lNode = lDoc1.ImportNode(lDoc2.DocumentElement.FirstChild, true);
 lDoc1.DocumentElement.AppendChild(lNode);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var doc= XDocument.Load("file1.xml");
var doc1= XDocument.Load("file2.xml");
doc.Root.Add(doc2.Root.Elements());
```

Comment: Simplest and the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee this format you can combine them by doing string manipulation:

- Read the first file, keep everything before "</AllNodes>"
- Read the second file, remove the part up to "<AllNodes>"
- Combine those strings.

This should be the fastest way since no parsing is needed.

```
const string RelevantTag = "AllNodes";

string xml1 = File.ReadAllText(xmlFile1);
xml1 = xml1.Substring(0, xml.LastIndexOf("</" + RelevantTag + ">"));

string xml2 = File.ReadAllText(xmlFile2);
xml2 = xml2.Substring(xml.IndexOf("<" + RelevantTag + ">") + "<" + RelevantTag + ">".Length, xml1.Length);

File.WriteAllText(xmlFileCombined, xm1 + xml2);
```

That said I would always prefer the safe way to the fast way.

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic options:

1. Parse the xml, combine the data structures, serialize back to xml.
2. If you know the structure, use some basic string manipulation to hack it.  For example, in the example above you could take the inside of allnodes in the two xml blocks and put them in a single allnodes block and be done.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution to me,  based on Jose Basilio answer, slightly modified,

```
var combinedUnique = xml1.Descendants()
    .Union(xml2.Descendants());
combinedUnique.First().Save(#fullName)
```

Comment: Thank you @user3510339 for the code, however it is saving the contents of the first XML file only. TIA

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this (using C#), I would create a class that I can deserialize this XML to (you can use xsd.exe to do this), and then loop through all the nodes in the object representing the first piece of XML and "Add" them to the AllNodes property of the object representing the second XML.

Then serialize the second class back out the XML, and it should look like your 3rd example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for the **fastest**:

If (and only if) the xml structure is always consistent: (this is pseudo code)

```
string xml1 = //get xml1 somehow
string xml2 = //get xml2 somehow
xml1 = replace(xml1, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>", "");
xml1 = replace(xml1, "<allnodes>", "");
xml1 = replace(xml1, "</allnodes>", "");
xml2 = replace(xml2, "<allnodes>", "<allnodes>\n" + xml1);
```

It's a giant hack but it's fast. Expect to see it on TheDailyWTF when your colleagues find it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case **the main solution did not work well**, the difference was that I had a List for a thousands of files when I take one element and try to merge with the first element I get OutOfMemory exception, I added an empty template with and empty row **(NodeA in this case)** to solve the weird problem of the memory and run smoothly.

I save the document in other process

```
XDocument xmlDocTemplate = GetXMLTemplate(); -- create an empty document with the same root and empty row element (NodeA), everything will be merge here.
List<XElement> lstxElements = GetMyBunchOfXML();

foreach (var xmlElement lstxElements)
{
    xmlDocTemplate
        .Root
        .Descendants("NodeA")
        .LastOrDefault()
        .AddAfterSelf(xmlElement.Descendants("NodeA"));
}
```