# How do I merge two XDocuments removing duplicates

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have two XML files (*.resx files) that I am trying to merge in to one removing duplicates, but am unable to do so. I've tried the following without any success:

```
            var resource1 = XDocument.Load("C:\\Resources.resx");

            var resource2 = XDocument.Load("C:\\Resources2.resx");

           // This results in a file with all the nodes from the second file included inside 
          // the root element of the first file to form a properly formatted, concatenated file.
            resource1.Descendants().FirstOrDefault().Add(resource2.Descendants().FirstOrDefault().Nodes());

            var nodeContent = new List<string>();               

            foreach (XElement node in resource1.Root.Elements())
            {                    

                if (nodeContent.Contains(node.ToString()))
                    resource1.Remove();
                else
                    nodeContent.Add(node.ToString());
            }

            resource1.Save("C:\\FinalResources.resx");
```

On the remove statement I get an InvalidOperationException - "The parent is missing.":

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should define, what is "duplicate" in your context. How do you compare two xml entries? By `name` attribute? By tag name? By content?

Comment: If still someone is looking for an answer to this Question then look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982597/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-combine-two-xml-files-into-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define an `EqualityComparer<XElement>` that will enable you to use the standard LINQ operators.

So, as a simple example I created this:

```
public class ElementComparer : EqualityComparer<XElement>
{
    public override int GetHashCode(XElement xe)
    {
        return xe.Name.GetHashCode() ^ xe.Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(XElement xe1, XElement xe2)
    {
        var @return = xe1.Name.Equals(xe2.Name);
        if (@return)
        {
            @return = xe1.Value.Equals(xe2.Value); 
        }
        return @return;
    }
}
```

So I can then start with these two XML documents:

```
<xs>
    <x>D</x>
    <x>A</x>
    <x>B</x>
</xs>

<xs>
    <x>E</x>
    <x>B</x>
    <x>C</x>
</xs>
```

And do this:

```
var xml1 = XDocument.Parse(@"<xs><x>D</x><x>A</x><x>B</x></xs>");
var xml2 = XDocument.Parse(@"<xs><x>E</x><x>B</x><x>C</x></xs>");

xml1.Root.Add(
    xml2.Root.Elements("x")
        .Except(xml1.Root.Elements("x"), new ElementComparer()));
```

Then `xml1` will look like this:

```
<xs>
    <x>D</x>
    <x>A</x>
    <x>B</x>
    <x>E</x>
    <x>C</x>
</xs>
```

Comment: @Si8 - What precisely didn't work? All of the code should work with a simple copy-paste.

Comment: The metge didnt add the second XDocument to the first one but I went different route. Thank you,

Comment: @Si8 - I think you might need to check your code. I've just copy/pasted the code into a new project and it worked fine for me. I'd like to track down the issue on this if I can.

Comment: Thank you. My XDocument is a Sharepoint ATOM feed so maybe that's why.

Comment: @Si8 - Does the ATOM feed XML contain namespaces other than just a default one?

Comment: Yeah... there are three separate ones.

Comment: @Si8 - You must apply the appropriate namespaces and then the code will work fine. The bottom-line is that when you said "this didn't work for me" you weren't referring to using my XML, but yours. Yell out if you need help adding in the namespace references.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most straight forward way is:

```
var resource1 = XDocument.Load("C:\\Resources.resx");
var resource2 = XDocument.Load("C:\\Resources2.resx");

foreach (XElement node in resource2.Root.Elements())
{                    
    if (resource1.Root.Contains(node)) continue;
    resource1.Add(node);
}

resource1.Save("C:\\FinalResources.resx");


public static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this XElement root, XElement e)
    {
        //or w/e equality logic you need
        return root.Elements().Any(x => x.ToString().Equals(e.ToString()));
    }
}
```

This will only merge first level entries tho. If you need deep merge, then you will have to set up a simple recursion (using the same loop for child elements).

Answer (score 0):

resource1.Remove(); is called twice and what it does is remove the root element. So the second time there is no longer a root element to remove from and thus throwing the exception.