# how to concatenate two XML string into single valid XML

Tags: c#, xml, stringbuilder

I'm trying to concatenate two string builder, each contains XML. 
when I add the `header` alone it works fine.. same with `details` but when I append... them and save to the database it gives me an error..

here's the error:

> {"XML parsing: line 1, character 418, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input"}

```
 public string XMLDoc(SalesForecastModel model)
        {
            string doc = string.Empty;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();

                writer.WriteStartElement("header");

                writer.WriteStartElement("SalesForecast");

                writer.WriteStartElement("EntryNumber");
                writer.WriteString(model.EntryNumber.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("EntryDate");
                writer.WriteString(model.EntryDate.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("Year");
                writer.WriteString(model.Year.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("Remarks");
                writer.WriteString(model.Remarks.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("RevisionID");
                writer.WriteString(model.RevisionID.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("Status");
                writer.WriteString(model.Status.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("CreatedBy");
                writer.WriteString(model.CreatedBy.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("CreatedDate");
                writer.WriteString(model.CreatedDate.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("LastModifiedBy");
                writer.WriteString(model.LastModifiedBy.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteStartElement("LastModifiedDate");
                writer.WriteString(model.LastModifiedDate.ToString());
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();

                writer.WriteEndDocument();

            }



            StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlWriter writer1 = XmlWriter.Create(builder1))
            {
                writer1.WriteStartDocument();
                writer1.WriteStartElement("details");
                foreach (SalesForecastDetailModel detail in model.Details)
                {
                    writer1.WriteStartElement("SalesForecastDetails");
                    writer1.WriteStartElement("MonthID");
                    writer1.WriteString(detail.MonthID.ToString());
                    writer1.WriteEndElement();
                    writer1.WriteEndElement();
                }
                writer1.WriteEndElement();
                writer1.WriteEndDocument();
            }
            return doc = builder.Append(builder1).ToString();
        }
```

Comment: 95% of answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982597/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-combine-two-xml-files-into-one. You can work out the rest and post self-answer (or vote as duplicate).

Comment: You're not trying to concatenate two StringBuilders. You're trying to combine two XML documents that just happen to be contained by StringBuilders. That's a totally different question than what you've asked, and one I'm quite certain has been asked here before. You might try searching on *combine XML content* or *insert XML nodes*.

Answer (score 1):

With XmlWriter

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication78
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string doc = string.Empty;

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder))
            {
                XElement salesForecast =
                    new XElement(
                        "SalesForecast",
                        new XElement(
                            "header",
                            new XElement("EntryNumber", model.EntryNumber),
                            new XElement("EntryDate", model.EntryDate),
                            new XElement("Year", model.Year),
                            new XElement("Remarks", model.Remarks),
                            new XElement("RevisionID", model.RevisionID),
                            new XElement("Status", model.Status),
                            new XElement("CreatedBy", model.CreatedBy),
                            new XElement("CreatedDate", model.CreatedDate),
                            new XElement("LastModifiedBy", model.LastModifiedBy),
                            new XElement("LastModifiedDate", model.LastModifiedDate)),
                        new XElement(
                            "details",
                            model.Details.Select(detail =>
                                new XElement(
                                    "SalesForecastDetails",
                                    new XElement("MonthID", detail.MonthID)))));
                writer.WriteNode(salesForecast);

                writer.WriteEndDocument(); //closes any open tags
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to concatenate two valid XML documents together. That does not create a valid XML document.

It's like if you had `<a>x</a>` (valid XML) & `<b>y</b>` (valid XML) and then just joined them like `<a>x</a><b>y</b>` (**invalid** XML).

You need to surround them with a new parent node or to nest one within the other. I'll assume a new parent node.

Now, also given that the structure can be moved around I think that there is a very nice output format. I'll also use `System.Xml.Linq` as it produces far easier code to read.

Try this:

```
public string XMLDoc(SalesForecastModel model)
{
    var xml =
        new XElement(
            "SalesForecast",
            new XElement(
                "header",
                new XElement("EntryNumber", model.EntryNumber),
                new XElement("EntryDate", model.EntryDate),
                new XElement("Year", model.Year),
                new XElement("Remarks", model.Remarks),
                new XElement("RevisionID", model.RevisionID),
                new XElement("Status", model.Status),
                new XElement("CreatedBy", model.CreatedBy),
                new XElement("CreatedDate", model.CreatedDate),
                new XElement("LastModifiedBy", model.LastModifiedBy),
                new XElement("LastModifiedDate", model.LastModifiedDate)),
            new XElement(
                "details",
                model.Details.Select(detail =>
                    new XElement(
                        "SalesForecastDetails",
                        new XElement("MonthID", detail.MonthID)))));

    return xml.ToString();
}
```